# Win32 NASM HelloWorld using Prinft results in AccessViolation

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

just read lots of tutorials and thought I'd give it a try with NASM on Windows. I tried several simple "Hello World" versions, one of which should use the _printf function to print the text to stdout.

Here's the code:

```
; Build by doing:
; nasm -f win32 -o test.o test.asm
; link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE libcmt.lib test.o

section .text
    global _start   
    extern _printf 

_start:
    push msg      ; Push msg on stack
    call _printf  ; Call printf
    add  esp, 4   ; Reset the stack 

    ; return 0
    xor eax, eax
    ret

; Our string, null terminated
msg: db "Hello World ", 13,10,0
```

I built it as described using "nasm -f win32 -o test.o test.asm" and linked it with the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 linker. Works well so far, but as soon as I try to run the executable I get an access violation. Exact linker command used:

```
link /subsystem:console /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib" /nodefaultlib /entry:start test.o libcmt.lib kernel32.lib
```

I did my best using OllyDBG to get to the error, but that didn't help either. Maybe someone here got an idea?...

Regards

Comment: The assembly looks OK. Exactly how did you link it with Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: The exact command was: link /subsystem:console /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib" /nodefaultlib /entry:start test.o libcmt.lib kernel32.lib

Comment: In general, to use the C library, you should name your entry point `main`  and let the C runtime start the process and then call your `main`.

Comment: Hi Jester. Just changed to "main" but that does not make no difference,...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew,...answer myself!
After a long research time and spending time in the debugger, here we go!

Using _printf and statically linking to "libcmt.lib" does require CRT initialization. When linking dynamically, this seems to be done automatically.

So only thing to do:

```
/entry:mainCRTStartup
```

Change the entry point to "mainCRTStartup", so everything gets initialized before the actualy "main" function gets called. It's a bit a shame that Visual Studio Library "libcmt.lib" in Version 12 does not return any meaningful information but crashes with an access violation, whereas Version 10 does return:

> runtime error R6030
>   - CRT not initialized

Problem solved. Funny,...annyoing too.